# Is port forwarding from outside a router technically possible?

Tags: ssh, port, router, forwarding

Something just crossed my mind. Say I have a router at home. To that router, there's a Linux machine connected, listening for SSH on port 22. Say I don't have any port forwarding configured.

The following criteria is met:

1. I know what internal IP adress my home computer has.
2. I know the public IP adress to my router.

Can I, from outside, connect to the router and say "Hey, this connection is for internal IP 10.0.1.8, please forward it"? Or is setting up static port forwarding from configuring the router always the only way to go?

If the answer to my initial question is yes, then how do I do it from say the Mac terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to setup port forwarding